# How to Programmatically show UISearchController in UINavigationController's leftbarbuttonitem and hide it after search?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to show a UISearchController within UINavigationController, when clicked on UINavigationController's rightbarbuttonitem and hide it when clicked on the button again.

[Initially the UINavigationBar will be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gke2F.png)

Later,

[The UINavigationBar should look like this, when search is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrE8t.png)

and further when clicked on close icon, the UINavigationBar should look like in image1.

The code I'm using to show searchcontroller is,

```
 func setUpSearchBar(){
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)

        self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        var cancelButton: UIButton

        let topView: UIView = self.searchController.searchBar.subviews[0] as UIView
        for subView in topView.subviews {
            if let pvtClass = NSClassFromString("UINavigationButton") {
                if subView.isKind(of: pvtClass) {
                    cancelButton = subView as! UIButton

                    cancelButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                    cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
                    cancelButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"close"), for: .normal)
                    cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                }
            }

        }

        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"Futura-Medium", size:20)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(red: 234/255, green: 234/255, blue: 234/255, alpha: 1.0)]

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 56/255, green: 192/255, blue: 201/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .black
       // self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
        let leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.searchController.searchBar)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavBarButton
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
   func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .clear

    }
    func pressButton(button: UIButton) {
        searchEvent.isEnabled = true

    }
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        print(searchController.searchBar.text)
    }
```

But this code shows navigation bar,but when clicked on cancel button, the pressButton event isn't getting triggered?why is that?

Comment: Rolled back. If you have a new question create a separate question post. You negate the answer, right or wrong, by changing the question. You may decide to accept / upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` property to `true` which manages to hide Navigation Bar and show a search bar in that area.

Comment: Thankyou! I made that working with a small fix, but I have a new issue can you help me out of that? Please check my updated question.